# Arranging my classes rails mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, mongoid

I have 4 user types

```
-SuperAdmin
-Admin
-Manager
-Tenant
```

I currently have 2 connector classes

```
-manager_approval
-reportapproval
```

Tenants create and own the Report class.

I need to make sure that Admin, SuperAdmin, Managers, and Tenants can access an instance of a Tenants.report

Currently I have the following setup but I am not sure if this is correct

```
class SuperAdmin
 include Mongoid::Document

 has_many :admins
 has_many :managers
 has_many :reports
end

class Admin
  belongs_to :super_admin
  has_many :manager_approvals, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :managers
  has_many :reportapprovals
  has_many :reports
end

class belongs_to :admin
  has_many :tenants
  has_many :reports
  has_many :reportapprovals, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :coupons
  has_many :manager_approvals, dependent: :destroy
end

class Tenant
 include Mongoid::Document

 has_one :report, dependent: :destroy
 has_one :tenant_record, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true
 has_many :reportapprovals, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true
 has_many :managers
end

class Reportapproval
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :tenant, inverse_of: :reportapprovals
  belongs_to :manager, inverse_of: :reportapprovals
  belongs_to :admins
  has_many :reports, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :manager_approvals
end

class ManagerApproval
 include Mongoid::Document

 belongs_to :admin, inverse_of: :managers, dependent: :destroy
 belongs_to :manager
 has_many :reportapprovals
 has_many :reports
end

class Report
 include Mongoid::Document

 belongs_to :tenant, dependent: :destroy
 has_and_belongs_to_many :reportapprovals
 has_and_belongs_to_many :managers, through: :reportapprovals
 has_many :admins, through: :managers
end
```

This doesn't feel right to me and wanted someone to review it. Ultimately, the report is created by a tenant, the manager can access the report, and the admin can access ALL reports the manager can access, and the SuperAdmin can access ALL reports from all managers. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Single Collection Inheritance

Use inheritance so that the different kinds of users are stuffed into the same collection:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
end

class Admin < User
end

class SuperAdmin < User
end
```

In the SQL world this is whats known as Single Table Inheritance. The schemaless nature of MongoDB makes removes a lot of the drawbacks of STI and makes it a quite powerful tool.

This would let you query all user types with:

```
User.where(name: 'Bob') # returns any subtype
```

Or a specific type of users:

```
Admin.where(name: 'Bob') # returns only documents with the class Admin.
```

This is especially important when dealing with authorization where you might only know the ID of a user but not the type.

### Let em roll

While having a User class and a Admin class (etc.) and setting up a complex class tree with escalating privileges may seem like a reasonable idea it seldom works well with reality. And has quite a few drawbacks:

- how do you handle when a user is promoted or even demoted?
- what if a user falls in multiple categories?

Instead consider a [tried and true pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) with Users and Roles which allows a lot of extendability. You can for example scope roles to specific resources or create a role hierarchy.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :roles

  def has_role?(role)
    self.roles.where(name: role).any?
  end

  def admin?
    has_role? :admin
  end

  def admin!
    self.roles.find_or_create_by!(name: :admin)
  end
end

class Role
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :user
  field :name, type: Symbol
end
```

Note that due to the way relations are declared on the class and not per instance the base user class will contain all the relations:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :roles

  # ...
  has_many :reports
  has_many :report_approvals

  # ...
end
```

While its potentially possible to add this to instances on runtime it seems quite hacky.

Comment: Also you should be consistent when naming - Reportapproval should be `ReportApproval - report_approval`

Comment: Great Answer! Because as you stated not every instance of the class will have the same privileges, I think the roles will do quite well to ok the instances.

Comment: One question, with the Single Table Inheritance, does the logic for each user still go into its own file and the inherentance logic goes into each file or is their just one file for ALL users and the inheritance logic goes at the top of that file?

Comment: I'm no quite t sure what you are asking. For the rails autoloading to work you would put each model  class in its own file `/app/models/admin.rb`, `/app/models/super_admin.rb`.

Comment: Yes but in your answer you show inheriting like
 
````class User
  include Mongoid::Document
end

class Admin < User
end````

Is that within each model or just one model referencing the different models

Comment: Nevermind I re-read and think I just figured it out. You just added a User model that contains the inheritance logic for the other models

Comment: Right, its just plain old inheritance. Any fields or relations that you add in the `User` class will trickle down to the subclasses. Mongoid just puts the documents in the `users` collection since that is where `include Mongoid::Document` is . http://rohitrox.github.io/2013/08/30/single-table-inheritance-in-mongoid/

Comment: Great! Again, thanks for the answer! I swear this stuff always has you learning!